# How to pass value to module from controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

### Module:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myModule", []);
})();

(function (module) {
    "use strict";
    module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
 }]);

})(angular.module("myModule"));
```

### Controller:

```
myModule.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
      $scope.testvalue = "testvalue";
}
```

Now I want $scope.testvalue inside module.config,

```
(function (module) {
    "use strict";
    module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        var controllerdata = $scope.testvalue;
 }]);
```

How can I do this? how to pass value from controller to module.config (both are in same module scope)

Comment: You should not try to do that. Module config gets called before the controller. It is independent of any page/controller. If you want to do it the other way round(use config data in controller), you can create an angular provider. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

Not every variable has the privilege to appear in the config blocks. In your case, you cannot access the scope variable in your module's config block.

But there are alternatives:

1. **Use a constant**: Constants are available in config blocks, and are useful for static values that don't change.
2. **Use a provider**: If you need a custom configurable service available in your app, you can create an angular provider to make it customizable in the config blocks.

Comment: can u plz tel me how to do the above. pls give me some sample code

Comment: @apps -- Please refer to [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for docs and examples.